# Load one file into another file

Tags: javascript, html

I have one file called index.html and I have 2 more files whose contents I would like to load in the div of index.html using js.

**index.html**

```css
.load_content_div{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  border:thin black solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Some Content</div>

<div> <a href="about.html"> about us</a> </div>
<div> <a href="contact.html"> contact us</a> </div>

<div class="load_content_div">

</div>
```

**about.html**

About Us Data

**contact.html**

Contact Us Data

How can I do this using only javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Execute AJAX calls from the main page to the other pages, and then in the return of those AJAX calls set the innerHTML of the desired elements equal to the returned content.

Comment: i don't know how to do it?

Comment: @Rishi [This link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) gives a great tutorial of exactly what you're trying to do.  Give it a try and, if you get stuck, try posting a more specific follow-up quiestion.